# What does the word "Post" mean written on this electrical box cover?

Tags: electrical

I want to add an electrical outlet to my basement. There is already an electrical box attached to one of the floor/ceiling joists with a wire going in. No wire coming out.

Inside is one set of wires (1 white, 1 black, 1 ground/bare). I have not tested to see if this is live yet. It has the word "post" written on the cover. What does this mean, and is it safe to add an electrical outlet to this box?

[image]

Comment: How do you have 2 wires of each color if there's a wire going in and no wire going out?  There must be 2 cables entering the box - do you know where they go?

Comment: Looked again, looks like it was just an extra set of wires connected with wire nuts. There is only one set coming from the sheath.

Comment: what is above this box?

Comment: Perhaps the original intent was to provide power to an outside lamp post?

Comment: Follow the wire, where does it go?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this perhaps was slated for the connection point between the UF cable going to a post/yard light and the indoor NM switch leg.